# Sending email from Ruby via Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

This code fails to send email (nothing happens at all - no error either). What am I doing wrong?

/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "sample@gmail.com"

  def email_test()
    @user = 'recipient@gmail.com'
    mail(to: @user, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

/config/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "sample@gmail.com",
  :password => "password123",
}
```

I invoke the code in folder /app/mailers/. Here I run:

`rails runner UserMailer.email_test`

Is it because I am putting the gmail smtp settings in development.rb, but am running this code in command line?

I've already turned on 'access to less secure apps' in my gmail account. So confused, please advise thanks!

Comment: Is the sender the same of the receiver?

Comment: Could you try setting the authentication to `:plain`? Also, the environment shouldn't be a problem, type `Rails.env` at the console if you want to be sure.

Comment: May be your server not working with send mail, try first this `echo "The test body" | mail -s "The test subject" your@email.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails 3:

```
rails runner "UserMailer.email_test.deliver"
```

For Rails 4:

```
bin/rails runner "UserMailer.email_test.deliver_now"
```